# Export HTML table to Excel with styles. Code Link: https://github.com/kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, export-to-excel

I have tried on the stuff of exporting my `HTML` table as `.xlsx` file using `TableExport`. I have done this successfully and it works great(thanks to them), but I have a simple query, when exporting my HTML table as .xlsx file, ***is it possible to add my styles into excel cell?***. For example, in default excel cell show numbers/numeric data's are right aligned and text data's are in left aligned. See this image:

[image]

So the question is, **Can we export file's specified with our own styles like *"text-align:right;"* to all the cell?**, without doing it manually in excel sheet.

So the expected result is like:

[image]

And here is my code

Comment: you forgot to attach the code

Comment: you can download the code on [this link](https://github.com/kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin).

Comment: @RameshMaharjan

Comment: I haven't worked on javascript and jquery so I have no idea about your question. In your question you said `And here is my code` but there was no code so I just commented for you to provide codes so that others can help you. Update your question with codes and update the tags so that others can reach you fast